# Scan HTML for unused assets in folders

Tags: html, cleanup

I have an aging website I'm managing and I'd like to remove all unused external files (.css, .jpg, .js, etc.) that are currently in various folders all over the site.

Is there a tool out there that can help me identify and/or remove these for me?

Comment: This question is related and might also have helpful suggestions:
http://serverfault.com/questions/131778/deleting-old-unused-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several utilities to download entire websites. Run one, follow all links to your site, but not to any other sites. Anything not in the resulting archive could be deleted.

Comment: Unless someone else is linking to the content. Best to move the unused content elsewhere then check your logs for a while afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I cut the website size in half. I ended up using http://www.httrack.com/.

Comment: Iain brings up a good point. Is it your policy to disallow deeplinking? If not, then you could follow his advice of archiving the existing site and then watching your logs.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to write a script that reduces a few months worth of raw log files down to just the URI part of them, then gathers a directory listing, and finally loops through the directory listing and lists everything that doesn't have a corresponding appearance in the condensed log file.

Comment: ya know? I'm in the same boat as the OP. I think there may be a market for such a script...

Answer (score 0):

Several editors like Dramweaver and Expression Web have built-in utilities to detect unlinked files in the site. I don't know of any free tools, but I'd be surprised if there isn't.